# how to call jquery function within jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

hey everyone I had 3 radio button (bus, air, boat) and 3 jquery function (bus, air,boat) that bind my 1 dropdown/combobox. now my problem how to call jquery function for bus if I click radio button for bus.. My data binding classes `$(".orig_bus")`, `$(".orig_air")` and `$(".orig_boat")`, I wrote 3 different function, if i select radio button `submit_buttonAir` - it call for  `$(".orig_air")` my html div should be (`div class='orig_air'`)

```
    ############### Bus Radio Button#################
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#submit_buttonBus').click(function() {
         if ($('input[name=bus]')[0].checked == true)
         {
               alert('Travel By Bus Ride!');
               bus_z = true; 
               plane_z = false; 
               boat_z = false; 
               $('input[name="plane"]')[0].checked = false;
               $('input[name="boat"]')[0].checked = false;
        }
     });
    });
    ##################################################
    Bus Binding for Dropdown
    ##################################################
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var theme = getTheme();
    // prepare the data
            var source ={
        datatype: "json",
        datafields: [{ name: 'places'},],
        url: 'data.php'
    };
    var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
    $(".orig_bus").jqxDropDownList(
    {
        source: dataAdapter,
        theme: theme,
        width: 300,
        height: 24,
        selectedIndex: 0,
        displayMember: 'places',
        valueMember: 'places'
    });   
        });
        ####################################################
        HTML DIV dropdown
        ####################################################
         <div name="list" class="orig_bus"></div>
```

Comment: my data binding are, class $(".orig_bus"), $(".orig_air") and $(".orig_boat") if i select radio button submit_buttonAir - orig_air my html div should be  (div class=orig_air)

Comment: Add that to the question, it's hard to read in the comments.

Comment: Can you be a little more elaborate and clear?

Comment: I assume what you want to do is hide/display different dropdowns bases the selected option, like if `bus` radio is selected then display bus dropdown is that what you want

Comment: I only have 1 dropdown. populate it based on radio button.

Comment: mohkhan sorry if I click radio button air my dropdown should populate data from air table (mysql)

Comment: @Arun P Johny exactly :(